# How to find the documentation for Interpolation?

Tags: interpolation

I'm trying to understand the second line in this code

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate(function(points) { return points.join("A 1,1 0 0 1 "); })
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
```

(it comes from this example). But when checking the documentation (even for d3 v3), I don't seem to find help for this. What does the string `"A 1,1 0 0 1 "` mean at the end of the line? And how can this be written in the v4 version?

Thanks for all input!

Best,
Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

That string seems to be an SVG elliptical arc command:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands

So instead of calculating interpolating points, connecting the dots is apparently left to the SVG renderer using such an arc that sort of automatically interpolates with a smooth stroke.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Indeed, I now see this looks like the elliptical arc commands of SVG. How is it possible to write this in v4 code? Thanks!